# Rails Cookies to manipulate database entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to create a Rails app and I have a database consisting of author and a quotation by that author.

Now different users can choose to destroy or kill quotations from the database however it must only be deleted for that particular user i.e other users should still be able to see quotes that they didn't delete even if another user did.

I know that I would need to implement cookies but other than that I am unsure how to proceed. Can anyone point me to a tutorial or give me some pointers to get started on this complex task?

Comment: I would recommend to first get used to Rails, learn the basics of the language, start a small demo application and then start developing the application you just mentioned. It doesn't make sense to point you to a tutorial if you don't understand the concepts of the language used.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

You surely have a `User` model in your application - one 'Rails-like' way to go about this would be to add a [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) relationship between `User` and `Quotation`.

This creates a relationship between each individual user and 'their' quotations. This relationship can be deleted without actually deleting a quotation, so all quotations would still be available to other users. If you want each user to be able to see all quotations by default, you would need to set up the relationship in advance.

Assuming you are using Devise to log your users in, all you'd need to do then is to replace `Quotation.all` with `current_user.quotations` in whichever controller you are using to display quotations.

The Rails guide linked above is quite helpful but basically you just need to add something like the following:

```
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :quotations

  before_create :add_quotations

  def add_quotations
    self.quotations << Quotation.all
  end
  #etc...
end

class Quotation
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  #etc...
end
```

and then run a migration adding a new table called `users_quotations` with the columns `user_id` and `quotation_id`.

**EDIT**

As @Yule pointed out this wouldn't let users see any quotations that were created after they were, and it would be quite annoying to have to set up the join tables in advance, so a more efficient way would be to have an `excluded_quotations` join table instead. So users can see all quotations except the ones that they have excluded.

Comment: This would have the issue of not maintaining new quotations for users. It'd be better to have the join table used as an 'exclusion' rather than 'inclusion' filter